# Set and reset text by clicking button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There are some buttons at my page i.e button "one", button "two" etc. There is a text too which contains "Set This".

Requirements:

1. When user click on the button "**One**",

   (a) the button should be turned to dark background color(Selected/Active state)

   (b) Text, "**Set this**" should be changed to text according to clicking button's text. In this case, "Set this" will be changed to "**Set One**"
2. When user click on the button "**One**" again,

   (a) the button should be returned to it's previous state(light background version)

   (b) Changed text ("**Set One**") should be reset and returned back to default state("**Set This**")

Same requirements for other buttons. I could make the requirements 1 and 2(a) But I can't make 2(b). How can I make it?

My fiddle Work: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/VFPLf/

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    $('.changeText').text($(this).data("text"));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding the problem correctly, this would probably be your best bet

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");    
    if ($('.changeText').text() == $(this).data("text")) {
       $('.changeText').text("This");
    } else{
       $('.changeText').text($(this).data("text"))
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VFPLf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Azw4t/)</kbd>

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);//cache selector
    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');//addClass to current element clicked and remove class from siblings
    $('.changeText').text($this.data("text"));
});
```

[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    $('.changeText').text($(this).data("text"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/Azw4t/2/

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
       {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('.changeText').text($(this).data("text"));
       }
    else if($(this).hasClass('active'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('active')
        $('.changeText').text("This");
    }
});
```